# Can't cast value of type UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

So I'm having a a VC which is embedded in a navigation controller which in turn is embed in a Parent VC with 2 more containers. For all three containers I'm using function (from Parent VC) to manipulate them to show them.

As can be seen in the picture when I'm click on the 3 lines button from Voice VC it crashing with `Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1b5614200) to 'Pro.VoiceParentViewController`
If i embed just the Voice Parent VC ..my back buttons dont work anymore `_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

cause

`po navigationController -> nil`

**EDIT**

```
class VoiceParentViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var container_voiceVC: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var container_menuVC: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var containerSettingsVC: UIView!


@IBOutlet weak var constraint_trailingVoiceContainer: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var constraint_leadingVoiceContainer: NSLayoutConstraint!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func menuTouched() {
    constraint_leadingVoiceContainer.constant = self.view.bounds.maxX
    constraint_trailingVoiceContainer.constant = 2*self.view.bounds.maxX
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (isCompleted) in
    }
}
```

.....

```
class VoiceViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



@IBAction func action_menu(_ sender: Any) {
    (self.parent as! VoiceParentViewController).menuTouched()
}
```

........

```
class NewConversationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    _ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: what do you want more exactly?

Comment: I think you container and child hierarchy  are not clear. Will you please share zoom out screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: @AmritTrivedi I've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Embedded your ProfileViewController and VoiceViewController in navigationcontroller.

### Edited

I think problem is using child controllers with container view. I might be wrong. But i have created a quick demo for you same as your navigation cycle. Checkout this code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1faFagqDZwpfRN7lzDPknQAeWGvhx3271

[image]

Comment: still crashing at the exact same point...when going to profile...instead working when going to a conversation

Answer (score 0):

Just embedded your `VoiceParentViewController` in navigation controller **instead of**  embedded `VoiceViewController` in navigation controller

Comment: Did that but now navigationController is nil...  
_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)  no longer works

Answer (score 0):

Embed `VoiceParentViewController` in the `NavigationController` then make sure the first `ViewController` is `VoiceParentViewController` and then this pushes `VoiceViewController`. This would make sure `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` works.